# Update other column value by relation(foreign key) SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

How we change(Update) child table column value When we change a value in a column of the parent table in SQLite Database with foreign key?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?  Are you asking for a query? trigger?

Comment: It is unclear what you are talking about. T-sql, Entity framework? Show us what you tried.

Comment: I,m want when i change Text Field value in [TBL_b] the Text Field value in [TBL_a] is change Automatically.
I,m using VS C# 2010 and SQLite ADO .Net.
how do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER parent_update
AFTER UPDATE OF primary_key ON parent_table
BEGIN
    UPDATE child_table SET parent_key=NEW.primary_key WHERE parent_key=OLD.primary_key;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The general formula goes like this:

```
1.  Disable or remove the FK constraint.
2.  Update the Parent PK, but keep a list of the Old_PK and the New_PK values.
3.  Update the child records using the New_PK(s), but matching on the Old_PK values.
4.  Enable or re-add the FK constraint.
```

Comment: I,m want when i change Text Field value in [TBL_b] the Text Field value in [TBL_a] is change Automatically. I,m using VS C# 2010 and SQLite ADO .Net. how do this?